# Chrome DevTools: Triangle warning icon on Timeline view, what is it?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Warning icon on Google Chrome Developer Tools Timeline View]

Does anyone know what the triangular warning icon on Google Chrome Developer Tools Timeline View represents? When I hover over it, click it etc - there's no different information provided than for any of the other events. The event itself doesn't look to be long either, I can't work out what it's warning me about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This warning sign means that some code (e.g. `element.offsetHeight` or `document.width`) has triggered a **synchronous** layout event, which can adversely affect the performance in some cases. You should be able to see the associated stack trace if you expand the event tree.

A full explanation of this triangle and what it means is in the DevTools documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline#locating-forced-synchronous-layouts

[image]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline-images/forced_layout.png))</sub>

It includes a [Forced Synchronous Layout demo](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) to understand it better.